# java Generic Type vs Abstract class for parameter

Tags: java, generics, parameters, abstract, generic-type-argument

I'm studying Java Generic type.

I have the abstract class AbstractInputdata.

```
public abstract class AbstractInputData {
....
}
```

Some class that extend AbstractInputData

```
public class Email extends AbstractInputData{
...
}
public class Mobile extends AbstractInputData{
...
}
......
```

A.

```
public class ProcessorA {
public static boolean isCustomData(AbstractInputData abstractInputData) {
....
}
}
```

B.

```
public class ProcessorB {
public static <T extends AbstractInputData> boolean isCustomData(T t) {
...
}
}
```

Is there any difference between A and B?

Comment: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGeneric.html, which might help you to understand generic

Answer (score 5):

The only difference is that the second method with appear as a generic typed method via Reflections.  It's behaviour will be the same except in odd cases like this

```
processorB.<MyType>isCustomData(t); // won't compile unless t is a MyType
```

You would have to tell it what type you expect it to match, which isn't that useful IMHO.

Comment: @SayemAhmed Generics has been around 9 years and it's still confusing.  Imagine how confusing lambda's will be :P

Answer (score 2):

Since your methods only produce a boolean, there is no difference. But in case you want to return the input you can use B to preserve the generic type:

```
public class ProcessorB {
  public static <T extends AbstractInputData> boolean isCustomData(T t) {
    ...
  }
  public static <T extends AbstractInputData> T copyCustomData(T t) {
    ...
  }
}
```

ProcessorA could only return an object of type AbstractInputData while processorB returns Email or Mobile depending on the parameter type.

Comment: +1. thanks. After I test some case, finally I got it. @TomWolk